# Empty password input value on autocomplete (React.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete

After my login form is autocompleted by the browser, the queried password input's value is empty. After I click into the password field, the value gets magically available, also there are many events fired by the browser that don't make sense. *(The `onChange` on password input is not among them.)*

> - Why is the value on `input[type=password]` empty?
> - Why the autocomplete on password input doesn't fire `onChange` event?
>   *( it fires on normal input )*
> - Bonus question: Why there is the second (unnecessary) focus/blur event?

### 1. Both inputs set to `type="text"`

- Both inputs get rendered once (no autocomplete)

[image: console1]

*note: My inputs are uncontrolled but stateful and I track state changes on focus, blur, change*

- `entered=true` when there is a value entered
- `focused=true` when `onFocus` fired, `=false` when `onBlur` fired
- `peek=true` when I need to programatically force `type` from `password` to `text`

### 2. Input set to `type="password"`

*(See how the form is autocompleted.)*

[image: form]

[image: console2]

- ...
- 2.render (**red arrow**) - Browser focused the input
- `onChange` fired on email input
- 3.render - Internal state changed (`entered=true`)
- 4.render - Browser unfocused the input
- *5.render* (**yellow arrow**) - Browser focused the input again?
- *6.render* - Browser unfocused the input
  Browser didn't make any changes to dom element
- **preview password** - changed input type to `text` programatically
- manual **validateForm()** - password is empty, form is invalid
- manual interaction also says the value is `""` empty

What is interesting is that after pressing the <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> in the browser, the value gets available and form gets rerendered - as when focusing the input by hand.

Comment: Thanks for putting effort into making your question easy to read.

Comment: Have tried both with controlled and uncontrolled inputs? Is it the same behavior?

Comment: @MartinChaov I haven't tried it with controlled inputs, but I will when I get back to this project.

Answer (score 1):

An issue on the React GitHub discussing this: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1159. Spoiler: it's been active since Feb 2014 with no resolution.

Possible workaround: making a custom change handler that listens to the native browser event instead of the react synthetic one. This is complicated by the fact that we're using custom input elements from our validation library instead of native inputs which I'm sure to have their own change handlers to re-validate and we don't want to break those

Another possible workaround: save refs to all the form fields and manually grab their `.value` before submitting rather than relying on the managed values in the state, which is decidedly non-reactive and definitely not ideal